# Saving jpeg retreived from React via API in rawFile(blob)

Tags: php, reactjs, blob, raw-file

Is there any option to save jpeg file sent via React as rawFile?
So, frontend uses React-admin, on submitting it sends JSON encoded object of a structure like this:

```
{
  "id":8,
  "client_photo":{
    "rawFile":{
      "path":"DSC_2024.jpg"
    },
    "src":"blob:http://localhost/some-path",
    "title":"DSC_2024.jpg"
  }
}
```

I'm trying to save it on a server with PHP-script. The problem is that `$_FILES` and `$_POST` variables are empty, so the only source I have is that "src" field of the "client_photo" field received from React. How am I supposed to do that?

Comment: You need to start by modifying how you are sending this on the client side. `"src":"blob:…` is nothing you can actually access on the server side, only on the client side do you have access to such BLOB URL objects.

Comment: Unfortunately, the project uses third-party resources and I can't manage to understand how do I change it in order to reach my goal.. Sad situation..

Answer (score 0):

Use **filereader** to read the file and convert it as per your requirement and save it in DB.

Comment: Is that a library or what?

Comment: yes that is a library
Check out this link https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FileReader